# Fetch XML restapi with Apollo returns Unexcpected token

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, apollo

I start building my ApolloClient. It looks like this

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, HttpLink } from "@apollo/client"
//import { RestLink } from "apollo-link-rest"
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch"
const xml2js = require("xml2js")

const parseXmlResponseToJson = xml => {
// The function is not being fired
  const { parseString } = xml2js
  let jsonFeed = null
  parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    jsonFeed = result
  })

  return jsonFeed
}

const restLink = new HttpLink({
  uri:
    "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml",
  responseTransformer: async response =>
    response.text().then(xml => parseXmlResponseToJson(xml)),
  fetch,
})

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: restLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})
```

The provider looks like this

```
import React from "react"
import { client } from "../apollo"
import { ApolloProvider as Provider } from "@apollo/client"

function ApolloProvider({ children }) {
  return <Provider client={client}>{children}</Provider>
}

export default ApolloProvider
```

And the query I try to use looks like this

```
import React from "react"
import gql from "graphql-tag"
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client"

const APOLLO_QUERY = gql`
  {
    note {
      to
      from
      heading
      body
    }
  }
`

const Component = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(APOLLO_QUERY)

  console.log("Apollo data", loading, error, data)

  The error will return with Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2 
  // ...
```

I have been struggling with this for days. What am I doing wrong? I try to make it work with w3schools very simply xml example https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml

Comment: check if `responseTransformer` is fired, log response ... if async then await ... make it running in live react app, then move into gatsby env

Comment: It is not fired. If I write responseTransformer: async response =>
    response.text().then(xml => console.log(xml)) - changes nothing in log

Comment: log at the beginning, not at the end of chain .. use 'normal' { body fn def }

Comment: Sorry, but still no changes after responseTransformer: async response => console.log('response', response)

Comment: query not marked @rest ?